# shell script in PHP/HTML

Tags: python, php, html, shell

i have a shell script that will grep a python3 from ps aux

shell script (pythoncheck.sh)

```
if ps aux | grep -v "grep" | grep "python3" ; then echo "found" ; fi
```

how do i call this script in html or php, when click a button, if result it 'found' status change to green and if null the status change to red

is this possible with PHP ?

Comment: @feverdream plain wrong

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) function in PHP.

One way could be to create a PHP file that runs the script and then echos the result, then you can make a network request to this file when the button is clicked and use the response to change your status color.

#### py-check.php

```php
echo shell_exec('if ps aux | grep -v "grep" | grep "python3" ; then echo "found" ; fi
')
```

#### index.html

```
<button onclick="pyCheck">Check Python Status</button>

<script>
  function pyCheck() {
    fetch('/py-check.php')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(function(text) {
        if (text === found) {
          // Set status green here ✅
        } else {
          // Set status red here 
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Request failed', error)
      });
  }
</script>
```